# Printing my realtime output to txt file doesnt work python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, printing

My script prints every second the bitcoin price but i want the output printed to my txt file but it prints only 1 price to the txt file but i want every output to my txt file

**My code**

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()

def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD',
                     verify=False)
    soup =\
        bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    price =\
        soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'D(ib) smartphone_Mb(10px) W(70%) W(100%)--mobp smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].\
            find('span').text
    return price


while True:
    print('Bitcoin prijs: ' + str(parsePrice()),'  ::  ',x.strftime("%d, %B"))

     with open("koersen.txt", "w") as out_file:
       for i in range(len(parsePrice())):
          out_string = ""
            out_string += str(parsePrice())
          out_string += "," + str(a)
            out_string += "\n"
          out_file.write(out_string)
```

Comment: I think this is because it is overwriting. Consider updating your existing text file from second itterance.

Answer (score 2):

Here

`with open("koersen.txt", "w") as out_file:`

You are openning file in write mode. So it overwrites all the previous data. Open it in append mode: `"a"` or `"w+"`

**Update**

Try writing to your file like this:

```py
while True:
    print('Bitcoin prijs: ' + str(parsePrice()),'  ::  ',x.strftime("%d, %B"))

    with open("koersen.txt", "w+") as out_file:
        out_string = str(parsePrice()) + "\n"
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

Comment: It only prints 5 times the output to the txt file but the script is running

Comment: @hylkest In this line: `out_string += "," + str(a)`, I don't see variable `a` already defined. And instead of using `for` loop, you can write the data to file all at once

Comment: thank u for reacting so fast, i deleted  `+ str(a)` i saw that mistake. 
I'm pretty new with python so can you explain how i write all the data at once to the "koersen.txt" file

Comment: @hylkest I've updated the answer with code. If this helps, click the tick button on the left side of my answer to accept it. Feel free to ask if things aren't clear

Comment: It only prints one time the output to the txt file. and in the console i have like 60 lines of output

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to Stackoverflow. You can try changing below code and then let me know if it works for you.

```
 with open("koersen.txt", "w") as out_file:
   for i in range(len(parsePrice())):
      out_string = ""
        out_string += str(parsePrice())
      out_string += "," + str(a)
        out_string += "\n"
      out_file.writelines(out_string)
```

instead of write, use writelines.

Comment: It only prints 5 times the output to the txt file but the script is running

Comment: It depends on your parsePrice() length, if you think it is changing constantly, then better call this again everytime it changes

Comment: It changes like every second so then i have to call it again like 9999 times?

Comment: I believe yes or integrate with the part which gets values every second

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening a file, you can also directly log to `STDOUT` console and then use `tee` to write to a file direclty.This will allow you view the lines in the terminal directly and also save to file.
For this you just need print statements in and your file.
and your final command will be 
`python file.py | tee output.txt`

Comment: I am new to python i just need a simple way :)